# Moving down/up row of s:DataGrid in Flex 4.5 using ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, flashbuilder4

Recently started Flex. Had some practice on how to use services in PHP that Flex client asks via zend AMF. As a part of my project I am planning to load data from Mysql using PHP (via service) and display it in a s:DataGrid.
For this purposes I'm keen on knowing is it possible to move up/down datagrid row using ActionScript 3.0 depending on, say,specific row[r1][c1]'s value.

To be more in detail:

Think that OnTimer event datagrid's content will be updated and sorted by column Time and dislplayed by ascending order, whenever i update the time the row which it's column's value was modified should move down or up using Animation like this example from Adobe Center
http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/devnet/networkmonitor/main.html [switch to the grid mode on top of the site]

Tutorials or links (source codes ) are welcome!!!

Comment: You can actually see the source code for that component.
Click right on the swf and select "view source".
You will notice that it is not a default datagrid component.Cheers

Comment: Absolutely @Dennis! Source code is available. As i looked at it there's has been user developed grid layout class which I hardly read them. So how about talking the <s:DataGrid> class? Does it has methods to change the back color(of a row) or assign styles to a specific rows or columns on event handlers? 'cause I'd like to add a sort of blinking row functionality to my flex app.

Comment: On runtime I can assign to even/odd rows by simple add property to alternatingRowColors="[0xFFFFFF, 0xEDFFE9]" but how to set this color using actionscript?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking for dataprovider sorting based on the field that you want to sort upon. Also, look for some effects(examples in adobe docs) to get that kind of effects in your view.

Comment: OK, just downloading references, need to look over them!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selectedIndex property of the dataProvider ..
or selectedItem property on the grid to select the item pro grammatically